# Creating a custom histogram

Tags: graphics, data, histograms

Let's create some sample data

```
Clear["Global`*"];
n = 10000;
data0 = Table[{RandomReal[{-1, 1}], RandomReal[{-1, 1}], 
RandomInteger[{0, 50}], RandomInteger[{-2, 5}]}, {i, 1, n}];
```

and make a selection

```
data = Select[data0, (#[[4]] > 0) &];
```

Now let's create the histogram

```
datan = Table[Abs[data[[i, 3]]], {i, 1, Length[data]}];
P0 = Histogram[datan, Automatic, "Probability", ChartStyle -> Gray, 
ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[None], Frame -> True, 
FrameLabel -> {"t", "P"}, RotateLabel -> False, 
LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 20], 
Epilog -> {Red, Thick, Dashed, 
Line[{{#, 0}, {#, 1}} &@Last@Commonest[datan]]}, PlotRange -> All,
PlotRangePadding -> 0.001, AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 550]
```

[image]

The histogram corresponds to those data for which the fourth column is an integer 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5. Now I want the following: Split each column of the histogram in five bits (with different color), thus showing the contribution of each of the five possibilities (1, 2, 3, 4, 5).

I use version 9.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [`WeightedData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WeightedData.html) and [`GatherBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GatherBy.html). Both of these were available in version 9.

```
n = 10000;
SeedRandom[123]
data0 = ArrayFlatten[{{
     RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, 2}], 
     RandomInteger[{0, 50}, {n, 1}], 
     RandomInteger[{-2, 5}, {n, 1}]}}];
data = Select[data0, (#[[4]] > 0) &];
```

I scale the weights to the probabilities and use `"Count"` so that the stacked values are the correct probabilities.

```
WeightedData[#[[All, 1, 2]], #[[All, 2]]/Length@data] & /@
  Sort /@
   Sort@Map[
     First@# -> Length@# &,
     GatherBy[data[[All, {4, 3}]], {First, Last}],
     {2}] //
 Histogram[#, {1}, "Count",
   ChartLayout -> "Stacked",
   ChartLegends -> Range@5,
   ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[Gray],
   Epilog -> {Red, Thick, Dashed, 
     Line[{{#, 0}, {#, 1}} &@Last@Commonest[data[[All, 3]]]]}] &
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

This compares directly to the unstacked probability histogram.

```
Histogram[data[[All, 3]], {1}, "Probability",
 Epilog -> {Red, Thick, Dashed, 
   Line[{{#, 0}, {#, 1}} &@Last@Commonest[data[[All, 3]]]]}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally just split the data by the fourth column as

```
Do[ dat[i] = Select[data, (#[[4]] == i) &][[All, 3]]; , {i, 1, 5}]
```

and then plot them using the option `ChartLayout -> "Stacked"`

```
Histogram[Table[dat[i], {i, 1, 5}], Automatic, "Probability", ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[None], Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"t", "P"}, RotateLabel -> False, LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 20], Epilog -> {Red, Thick, Dashed, Line[{{#, 0}, {#, 1}}@Last@Commonest[datan]]}, PlotRange -> All, PlotRangePadding -> 0.001, AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 550,  ChartLayout -> "Stacked"]
```

You can then style it with `ChartStyle` as you wish.